# How do I disallow or block the passing of stack allocated variables?

Tags: c++, architecture, stl

I have a class utilizing an std::forward_list like so:

```
void Foo::AddBar(Bar* _bar)
{
  Bars.push_front(_bar);
}

void Foo::DeleteBar(Bar* _bar)
{
  for (forward_list::iterator index = Bars.begin(); index != Bars.end(); ++index)
  {
    if (_bar == *index)
    {
      delete _bar;
      forward_list.remove(_bar);
    }
  }
}
```

If I pass a stack allocated variable, in debug/release it will give me a runtime error, in production it will "mangle" the heap.

```
Bar bar;
foo.AddBar(&bar);
foo.DeleteBar(&bar); // Memory corruption on "delete _bar"
```

How do I prevent Foo::AddBar from accepting stack allocated data?  Is there a better way to design this?

---

**Edit** 6/21/13

Containing the `delete _bar;` and `forward_list.remove(_bar);` inside the for loop, causes a runtime error when the iterator increments.

I've opted to keep ownership control entirely in Foo and using a template like so:

```
template<class T> T* AddBar()
{
    Bar* object = new T();
    Bars.push_front(object);
    return object;
}
// Usage looks like...
Process* pid = foo.AddBar<MyBar>(); // adding a subclass of Bar
```

I'm using the pointer as a PID -- for lookup purposes. I could always return `int` to prevent the user from `delete`ing without first casting it.  Oh, and for arguments I could do `AddBar(void* arguments)`

Comment: "disallow [UB]". In C/C++? Hahaha.

Comment: You can't simply store pointers (or references) to local variables. You have to store copies.

Comment: You could take something like boost::shared_ptr<Bar> as input instead of a raw pointer.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, Making copies is a good idea but I'm not sure it's the best solution for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply put, you can not. Pointer is a pointer. You should avoid them in the first place. If you chose to use them, create a policy of documentation and make the code  properly reviewed for it.

In your example transfer of ownership happens (or at least something halfway that part of design also stinks), you must document that. The function must be called with only objects that are created using certain ways. &bar must be caught on the review as violating that.

Comment: _"Pointer is a pointer. You should avoid them in the first place."_ I find blanket statements like this to be terrible advice. It's certainly a good idea to prefer strong/smart pointers but "raw pointers" can and should be used _when appropriate_. A well written set of coding guidelines will include lifetime and ownership semantics for both raw pointers and references. Raw pointers also allow you to indicate the value is _optional_ where-as a reference cannot since there no such thing as a null reference in C++.

Comment: "you must document that" and "must be caught on the review" breaks my intended functionality.  Specifically, this is a wrapper for boilerplate code on a microcontroller.  Meaning, if it misses review, it's going to be darn hard to debug. +1 for the truth!

Answer (score 1):

Change your interface and implementation to use `unique_ptr`.

While users can still wrap their stack pointer in `unique_ptr`, it is at least obvious that this is occuring.

```
struct Foo {
  typedef std::vector< std::unique_ptr<Bar> > bar_storage;
  bar_storage bars;
  Bar* AddBar( std::unique_ptr<Bar> );
  void DeleteBar( Bar* bar );
};
void Foo::AddBar(std::unique_ptr<Bar> bar)
{
  Bars.push_back(std::move(bar));
}

void Foo::DeleteBar(Bar* bar)
{
  for (bar_storage::iterator index = Bars.begin(); index != Bars.end(); ++index)
  {
    if (bar == *index)
    {
      Bars.erase(index);
    }
  }
}
```

what I have done is pushed the undefined behavior to the calling site, in particular:

```
Bar bar;
foo.AddBar(&bar); // does not compile
```

Instead, the caller is forced to:

```
foo.AddBar(std::unique_ptr<Bar>(&bar)); // user just did something really vulgar!
foo.DeleteBar(&bar); // Memory corruption on "delete _bar"
```

in particular, because your `foo` represents ownership of `Bar`s, the adding of `Bar` to `Foo` should only be done by the code that already owned the `Bar`.  Represent such sole-ownership as a `std::unique_ptr<Bar>` all the way back to creation, and those that you have the right to delete are `unique_ptr`, and those you don't are `Bar*`.

Comment: I'll be trying this out.  I also vaguely remember some pascal code (mac 7) that used handles and factory method pattern, might try that too.